# System error transferring Data from Excel to ACCESS

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a problem with some code to transfer Data from EXCEL to ACCESS.
Here is the code:

```
 Sub Export_Data()
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection 'dim the ADO collection class
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset 'dim the ADO recordset class
    Dim dbPath
    Dim x As Long, i As Long
    Dim nextrow As Long

    'add error handling
    'On Error GoTo errHandler:

    'Variables for file path and last row of data
    dbPath = ActiveSheet.Range("T2").Value
    nextrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Initialise the collection class variable
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

    'Check for data
    If Sheet3.Range("B4").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox " Add the data that you want tot send to MS Access"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    'Connection class is equipped with a —method— named Open
    '—-4 aguments—- ConnectionString, UserID, Password, Options
    'ConnectionString formula—-Key1=Value1;Key2=Value2;Key_n=Value_n;
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
    'two primary providers used in ADO SQLOLEDB —-Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0 —-Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
    'OLE stands for Object Linking and Embedding, Database

    'ADO library is equipped with a class named Recordset
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset

    'ConnectionString Open '—-5 aguments—-
    'Source, ActiveConnection, CursorType, LockType, Options
    rst.Open Source:="Transactions", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
    CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
    Options:=adCmdTable

    'you now have the recordset object
    'add the values to it
    For x = 4 To nextrow
    rst.AddNew
    For i = 2 = 1 To 21
    rst(Cells(1, i).Value) = Cells(x, i).Value
    Next i
    rst.Update
    Next x

    'close the recordset
    rst.Close
    ' Close the connection
    cnn.Close
    'clear memory
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing

    'communicate with the user
    MsgBox " The data has been successfully sent to the access database"

    'Update the sheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'Clear the data
    Sheet3.Range("A4:G10000").ClearContents
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

    'clear memory
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnn = Nothing
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Export_Data"
 End Sub
```

I get this error ....

> SystemError &H80040E4D -2147217843

What went wrong ??   All I can say is that it seems to finding difficulty picking up the data from EXCEL or  placing it into ACCESS

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error? With such a long code dump it's not really possible to guess.... I also recommend you use the [edit] link below the question to improve the indenting so that the code is easier to read.

Comment: I've never seen a For structure like `For i = 2 = 1 To 21`. Why the `= 2`? What do you think this accomplishes? Does your code even compile?

Comment: My Apologies ...  The  " For i = 2 = 1 To 21" should have read "For i = 2 to 21"

Comment: My Apologies ...  The  " For i = 2 = 1 To 21" should have read "For i = 2 to 21".    It should signify the number of columns wide the data to be transferred.    I don't think it got that far in the compiler.  But I think this is where the compiler gets the error

Comment: Edit your question to correct code and identify line that throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was working with a macro enabled Excel file and I ran into the same error

`SystemError &H80040E4D -2147217843`

For me, the user which executed the VBA file, had not the permissions to access the database.

You could check the permission your user has on the server (and database). It helped in my case.

Best

j